# How do you enable store visit conversions in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I noticed a new tab under conversions for a specific account but cant figure out how to enable it on other accounts.

Does anyone know how to enable this on other accounts?

[image: screenshot of new tab]

Answer (score 1):

You would want to go through this [support article on Store Visits](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7573498). It outlines what you need to start seeing data in this type of report. This was [announced in 2018](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9103401?hl=en) and was released to advertisers who are running local campaigns.

Do go through the Limits and caveats in the article as well.